# Using AWS Api Gateway generated iOS (Objective C) SDK with React Native and callbacks

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, react-native

I'm having some problems with getting data from the native part (Objective C) back to React Native when I try to use the generated API from AWS API Gateway.

I have set up a simple test gateway in aws and have also created a model for that resource, and it looks like this. Without the model I was unable to read the response from AWS in objective C.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "dummyConfigModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "config": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "placeholder": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "label": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "meta": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "height": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "width": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ok, so with that in place I then generated an API from AWS, and got it installed in my workspace. I followed the docs on http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html to call my native module (with callbacks).

```
const NFAWSManager = NativeModules.NFAWSManager;
    const config = NFAWSManager.call(
      'configGet', {
        'dummyKey': 'dummyValue'
      },
      this.callback);
```

I am planning on calling the AWS method by string so to avoid setting up new native methods for every change to the API, but for now the call method just performs "configGet".

The native part looks like this:

```
#import "NFAWSManager.h"
#import "NFReactTestAPIClient.h"

@implementation NFAWSManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(
  call:(NSString *)method
  params:(NSDictionary *)params
  callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback
)
{
  NSLog(@"Method was: %@", method);
  NSLog(@"Params was: %@", params);

  NFReactTestAPIClient *client = [NFReactTestAPIClient defaultClient];
  [[client configGet:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
      callback(@[task.error]);
    }
    else {
      NFDummyConfigModel *output = task.result;

      NSLog(@"DEBUG %@", output);

      callback(@[[NSNull null], output]);
    }

    return nil;
    }];
}
@end
```

Ok, so when I call this from React I basically get nothing. I get "{}". But if I hardcode something like a string or a dictionary, that will be received normally by React.

I guess what I need help with is to convert the task.result object to a format that can be passed to React. I suspect it could be the model?

Comment: Looks like by removing the model altogether on the response section in API Gateway turns the result into something that can be passed to react. However, by removing this I suspect the Java version of the API will get into problems. *I'll keep digging*

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually that the default model in AWS is the Empty model, which then resulted in the data being instances of the generated NFEmpty. By creating a proper model this was resolved.

Removing the model did work on iOS, but only for getting data, if I wanted to post a model would be absolutely necessary.